# Bootstrap 3 vertical affix menu example as in the docs - resizing issue

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to use Bootstrap 3 vertical scrollspy, however I cannot find any examples included in the source.

I went ahead and stripped out the documentation pages from here http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/ but I am getting some very strange resize bugs with the sidebar - specifically:

1. On page refresh the nav bar is positioned and works OK, but on page resize it can drop off past the footer, or disapear before the end of the content.
2. When refreshed and the browser view port shows the footer (and not the content), the side nav bar shows in the footer whereas is should stop and be aligned with the end of the content.
3. If the browser window is maximized, clicking on the navigation items does not scroll to the corresponding header element.

Video demo of my issues are here http://youtu.be/Px5I-wKZ0sA

[Pastebin post here](http://pastebin.com/Wfphqw6t) and code below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Home</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" />


    <style type="text/css">

body {
  position: relative; /* For scrollyspy */
  padding-top: 50px; /* Account for fixed navbar */
}

/* Keep code small in tables on account of limited space */
.table code {
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: normal;
}

/* Outline button for use within the docs */
.btn-outline {
  color: #563d7c;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-color: #e5e5e5;
}
.btn-outline:hover,
.btn-outline:focus,
.btn-outline:active {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #563d7c;
  border-color: #563d7c;
}

/* Inverted outline button (white on dark) */
.btn-outline-inverse {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: transparent;
  border-color: #cdbfe3;
}
.btn-outline-inverse:hover,
.btn-outline-inverse:focus,
.btn-outline-inverse:active {
  color: #563d7c;
  text-shadow: none;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-color: #fff;
}


.bs-docs-nav {
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.15);
  background-color: #563d7c;
  border-color: #463265;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.1);
}
.bs-docs-nav .navbar-collapse {
  border-color: #463265;
}
.bs-docs-nav .navbar-brand {
  color: #fff;
}
.bs-docs-nav .navbar-nav > li > a {
  color: #cdbfe3;
}
.bs-docs-nav .navbar-nav > li > a:hover {
  color: #fff;
}
.bs-docs-nav .navbar-nav > .active > a,
.bs-docs-nav .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #463265;
}
.bs-docs-nav .navbar-toggle {
  border-color: #563d7c;
}
.bs-docs-nav .navbar-toggle:hover {
  background-color: #463265;
  border-color: #463265;
}

.bs-footer {
  padding-top: 40px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  margin-top: 100px;
  color: #777;
  text-align: center;
  border-top: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
}
.footer-links {
  margin: 10px 0;
  padding-left: 0;
}
.footer-links li {
  display: inline;
  padding: 0 2px;
}
.footer-links li:first-child {
  padding-left: 0;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .bs-footer {
    text-align: left;
  }
  .bs-footer p {
    margin-bottom: 0;
  }
}

.bs-docs-home,
.bs-header {
  color: #cdbfe3;
  background-color: #563d7c;
}

 /* Masthead (headings and download button) */
 .bs-masthead {
  position: relative;
  padding: 30px 15px;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.15);
}
.bs-masthead h1 {
  font-size: 50px;
  line-height: 1;
  color: #fff;
}
.bs-masthead .btn-outline {
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding: 18px 24px;
  font-size: 21px;
}

/* Links to project-level content like the repo, Expo, etc */
.bs-masthead-links {
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding: 0 15px;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
}
.bs-masthead-links li {
  display: inline;
}
.bs-masthead-links li + li {
  margin-left: 20px;
}
.bs-masthead-links a {
  color: #fff;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .bs-masthead {
    text-align: left;
    padding-top:    140px;
    padding-bottom: 140px;
  }
  .bs-masthead h1 {
    font-size: 100px;
  }
  .bs-masthead .lead {
    margin-right: 25%;
    font-size: 30px;
  }
  .bs-masthead-links {
    padding: 0;
    text-align: left;
  }
}


/* Page headers */
.bs-header {
  padding: 30px 15px 40px; /* side padding builds on .container 15px, so 30px */
  font-size: 16px;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.15);
}
.bs-header h1 {
  color: #fff;
}
.bs-header p {
  font-weight: 300;
  line-height: 1.5;
}
.bs-header .container {
  position: relative;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .bs-header {
    font-size: 21px;
    text-align: left;
  }
  .bs-header h1 {
    font-size: 60px;
    line-height: 1;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 992px) {
  .bs-header h1,
  .bs-header p {
    margin-right: 380px;
  }
}


.bs-sidebar.affix {
  position: static;
}

/* First level of nav */
.bs-sidenav {
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  padding-top:    10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff;
  background-color: #f7f5fa;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

/* All levels of nav */
.bs-sidebar .nav > li > a {
  display: block;
  color: #716b7a;
  padding: 5px 20px;
}
.bs-sidebar .nav > li > a:hover,
.bs-sidebar .nav > li > a:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #e5e3e9;
  border-right: 1px solid #dbd8e0;
}
.bs-sidebar .nav > .active > a,
.bs-sidebar .nav > .active:hover > a,
.bs-sidebar .nav > .active:focus > a {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #563d7c;
  background-color: transparent;
  border-right: 1px solid #563d7c;
}

/* Nav: second level (shown on .active) */
.bs-sidebar .nav .nav {
  display: none; /* Hide by default, but at >768px, show it */
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}
.bs-sidebar .nav .nav > li > a {
  padding-top:    3px;
  padding-bottom: 3px;
  padding-left: 30px;
  font-size: 90%;
}

/* Show and affix the side nav when space allows it */
@media screen and (min-width: 992px) {
  .bs-sidebar .nav > .active > ul {
    display: block;
  }
  /* Widen the fixed sidebar */
  .bs-sidebar.affix,
  .bs-sidebar.affix-bottom {
    width: 213px;
  }
  .bs-sidebar.affix {
    position: fixed; /* Undo the static from mobile first approach */
    top: 80px;
  }
  .bs-sidebar.affix-bottom {
    position: absolute; /* Undo the static from mobile first approach */
  }
  .bs-sidebar.affix-bottom .bs-sidenav,
  .bs-sidebar.affix .bs-sidenav {
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
  }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
  /* Widen the fixed sidebar again */
  .bs-sidebar.affix-bottom,
  .bs-sidebar.affix {
    width: 263px;
  }
}


/* Space things out */
.bs-docs-section + .bs-docs-section {
  padding-top: 40px;
}

/* Janky fix for preventing navbar from overlapping */
h1[id] {
  padding-top: 80px;
  margin-top: -45px;
}

/* Common styles for all types */
.bs-callout {
  margin: 20px 0;
  padding: 15px 30px 15px 15px;
  border-left: 5px solid #eee;
}
.bs-callout h4 {
  margin-top: 0;
}
.bs-callout p:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
.bs-callout code,
.bs-callout .highlight {
  background-color: #fff;
}

/* Variations */
.bs-callout-danger {
  background-color: #fcf2f2;
  border-color: #dFb5b4;
}
.bs-callout-warning {
  background-color: #fefbed;
  border-color: #f1e7bc;
}
.bs-callout-info {
  background-color: #f0f7fd;
  border-color: #d0e3f0;
}

/* Navbars */
.bs-example .navbar:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
.bs-navbar-top-example,
.bs-navbar-bottom-example {
  z-index: 1;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden; /* cut the drop shadows off */
}
.bs-navbar-top-example .navbar-header,
.bs-navbar-bottom-example .navbar-header {
  margin-left: 0;
}
.bs-navbar-top-example .navbar-fixed-top,
.bs-navbar-bottom-example .navbar-fixed-bottom {
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
}
.bs-navbar-top-example {
  padding-bottom: 45px;
}
.bs-navbar-top-example:after {
  top: auto;
  bottom: 15px;
}
.bs-navbar-top-example .navbar-fixed-top {
  top: -1px;
}
.bs-navbar-bottom-example {
  padding-top: 45px;
}
.bs-navbar-bottom-example .navbar-fixed-bottom {
  bottom: -1px;
}
.bs-navbar-bottom-example .navbar {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .bs-navbar-top-example .navbar-fixed-top,
  .bs-navbar-bottom-example .navbar-fixed-bottom {
    position: absolute;
  }
  .bs-navbar-top-example {
    border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;
  }
  .bs-navbar-bottom-example {
    border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
  }
}

/* Pagination */
.bs-example .pagination {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

/* Pager */
.bs-example > .pager {
  margin-top: 0;
}

/* Example modals */
.bs-example-modal {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
.bs-example-modal .modal {
  position: relative;
  top: auto;
  right: auto;
  left: auto;
  bottom: auto;
  z-index: 1;
  display: block;
}
.bs-example-modal .modal-dialog {
  left: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

/* Example dropdowns */
.bs-example > .dropdown > .dropdown-menu {
  position: static;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

/* Example tabbable tabs */
.bs-example-tabs .nav-tabs {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

/* Tooltips */
.bs-example-tooltips {
  text-align: center;
}
.bs-example-tooltips > .btn {
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

/* Popovers */
.bs-example-popover {
  padding-bottom: 24px;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
}
.bs-example-popover .popover {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 260px;
  margin: 20px;
}

/* Scrollspy demo on fixed height div */
.scrollspy-example {
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  overflow: auto;
}


/*
 * Code snippets
 *
 * Generated via Pygments and Jekyll, these are snippets of HTML, CSS, and JS.
 */

.highlight {
  display: none; /* hidden by default, until >480px */
  padding: 9px 14px;
  margin-bottom: 14px;
  background-color: #f7f7f9;
  border: 1px solid #e1e1e8;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
.highlight pre {
  padding: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.highlight pre code {
  font-size: inherit;
  color: #333; /* Effectively the base text color */
}
.highlight pre .lineno {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 22px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  text-align: right;
  color: #bebec5;
}

/* Show code snippets when we have the space */
@media screen and (min-width: 481px) {
  .highlight {
    display: block;
  }
}


/* Responsive (scrollable) doc tables */
.table-responsive .highlight pre {
  white-space: normal;
}

/* Utility classes table  */
.bs-table th small,
.responsive-utilities th small {
  display: block;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: #999;
}
.responsive-utilities tbody th {
  font-weight: normal;
}
.responsive-utilities td {
  text-align: center;
}
.responsive-utilities td.is-visible {
  color: #468847;
  background-color: #dff0d8 !important;
}
.responsive-utilities td.is-hidden {
  color: #ccc;
  background-color: #f9f9f9 !important;
}

/* Responsive tests */
.responsive-utilities-test {
  margin-top: 5px;
}
.responsive-utilities-test .col-xs-6 {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.responsive-utilities-test span {
  padding: 15px 10px;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 1.1;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
.visible-on .col-xs-6 .hidden-xs,
.visible-on .col-xs-6 .hidden-sm,
.visible-on .col-xs-6 .hidden-md,
.visible-on .col-xs-6 .hidden-lg,
.hidden-on .col-xs-6 .visible-xs,
.hidden-on .col-xs-6 .visible-sm,
.hidden-on .col-xs-6 .visible-md,
.hidden-on .col-xs-6 .visible-lg {
  color: #999;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
.visible-on .col-xs-6 .visible-xs,
.visible-on .col-xs-6 .visible-sm,
.visible-on .col-xs-6 .visible-md,
.visible-on .col-xs-6 .visible-lg,
.hidden-on .col-xs-6 .hidden-xs,
.hidden-on .col-xs-6 .hidden-sm,
.hidden-on .col-xs-6 .hidden-md,
.hidden-on .col-xs-6 .hidden-lg {
  color: #468847;
  background-color: #dff0d8;
  border: 1px solid #d6e9c6;
}


/* For the variables, use regular weight */
#less-section label {
  font-weight: normal;
}

/* Downloads */
.bs-customize-download .btn-outline {
  padding: 20px;
}

/* Error handling */
.bs-customizer-alert {
  position: fixed;
  top: 51px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 1030;
  padding: 15px 0;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #d9534f;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.25);
  border-bottom: 1px solid #b94441;
}
.bs-customizer-alert .close {
  margin-top: -4px;
  font-size: 24px;
}
.bs-customizer-alert p {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
.bs-customizer-alert .glyphicon {
  margin-right: 5px;
}
.bs-customizer-alert pre {
  margin: 10px 0 0;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #a83c3a;
  border-color: #973634;
  box-shadow: inset 0 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,.05), 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.1);
}
</style>

</head>
<body>

<header class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top bs-docs-nav" role="banner">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button class="navbar-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".bs-navbar-collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a href="../" class="navbar-brand">Home</a>
    </div>
    <nav class="collapse navbar-collapse bs-navbar-collapse" role="navigation">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active">
          <a href="../menu1">Menu 1</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="../menu2">Menu 2</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="../menu3">Menu 3</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>

   <div class="bs-header" id="content">
      <div class="container">
        <h1>Titleblock Header</h1>
        <p>Some interesting catchy phrase better than Lorem ipsum.</p>
      </div>
    </div>


    <div class="container bs-docs-container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="bs-sidebar hidden-print" role="complementary">
                    <ul class="nav bs-sidenav">
                        <li><a href="#one">One</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#two">Two</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#three">Three</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div> <!-- end bs-sidebar -->
            </div> <!-- end col-md-3 -->   
            <div class="col-md-9">
                <div>
                    <h1 id="one">ONE</h1>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec ac felis sed eros bibendum tincidunt.
                    In vel lectus sit amet velit ullamcorper sollicitudin eu lacinia nisi.
                    Ut sagittis massa non ultricies hendrerit. Fusce non mauris augue. Phasellus imperdiet nisi quis ante commodo dignissim.
                    Aenean vel bibendum ipsum. Proin lobortis lobortis felis nec aliquet. Nunc vestibulum quis enim eu venenatis.
                    Vivamus consectetur justo nec quam euismod, ac pellentesque justo varius. Morbi vel dolor at nisi dictum convallis nec eu ligula. 
                    Duis consequat purus ut neque bibendum convallis. Aliquam tempor justo diam, sed dapibus diam laoreet aliquam. 
                    Curabitur feugiat neque quis nunc tincidunt porttitor. Integer in nulla metus. Proin pulvinar, massa quis bibendum ullamcorper, 
                    arcu arcu convallis mi, ut egestas eros dolor non lacus. Morbi id orci sapien.
                </div>
                <div>
                    <h1 id="two">TWO</h1>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec ac felis sed eros bibendum tincidunt.
                    In vel lectus sit amet velit ullamcorper sollicitudin eu lacinia nisi.
                    Ut sagittis massa non ultricies hendrerit. Fusce non mauris augue. Phasellus imperdiet nisi quis ante commodo dignissim.
                    Aenean vel bibendum ipsum. Proin lobortis lobortis felis nec aliquet. Nunc vestibulum quis enim eu venenatis.
                    Vivamus consectetur justo nec quam euismod, ac pellentesque justo varius. Morbi vel dolor at nisi dictum convallis nec eu ligula. 
                    Duis consequat purus ut neque bibendum convallis. Aliquam tempor justo diam, sed dapibus diam laoreet aliquam. 
                    Curabitur feugiat neque quis nunc tincidunt porttitor. Integer in nulla metus. Proin pulvinar, massa quis bibendum ullamcorper, 
                    arcu arcu convallis mi, ut egestas eros dolor non lacus. Morbi id orci sapien.
                </div>
                <div>
                    <h1 id="three">THREE</h1>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec ac felis sed eros bibendum tincidunt.
                    In vel lectus sit amet velit ullamcorper sollicitudin eu lacinia nisi.
                    Ut sagittis massa non ultricies hendrerit. Fusce non mauris augue. Phasellus imperdiet nisi quis ante commodo dignissim.
                    Aenean vel bibendum ipsum. Proin lobortis lobortis felis nec aliquet. Nunc vestibulum quis enim eu venenatis.
                    Vivamus consectetur justo nec quam euismod, ac pellentesque justo varius. Morbi vel dolor at nisi dictum convallis nec eu ligula. 
                    Duis consequat purus ut neque bibendum convallis. Aliquam tempor justo diam, sed dapibus diam laoreet aliquam. 
                    Curabitur feugiat neque quis nunc tincidunt porttitor. Integer in nulla metus. Proin pulvinar, massa quis bibendum ullamcorper, 
                    arcu arcu convallis mi, ut egestas eros dolor non lacus. Morbi id orci sapien.
                </div>
            </div> <!-- end col-md-9 -->
        </div> <!-- end row -->
    </div> <!-- end container -->


    <footer class="bs-footer" role="contentinfo">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <h1>FOOTER GOES HERE</h1>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec ac felis sed eros bibendum tincidunt.
                    In vel lectus sit amet velit ullamcorper sollicitudin eu lacinia nisi.
                    Ut sagittis massa non ultricies hendrerit. Fusce non mauris augue. Phasellus imperdiet nisi quis ante commodo dignissim.
                    Aenean vel bibendum ipsum. Proin lobortis lobortis felis nec aliquet. Nunc vestibulum quis enim eu venenatis.
                    Vivamus consectetur justo nec quam euismod, ac pellentesque justo varius. Morbi vel dolor at nisi dictum convallis nec eu ligula. 
                    Duis consequat purus ut neque bibendum convallis. Aliquam tempor justo diam, sed dapibus diam laoreet aliquam. 
                    Curabitur feugiat neque quis nunc tincidunt porttitor. Integer in nulla metus. Proin pulvinar, massa quis bibendum ullamcorper, 
                    arcu arcu convallis mi, ut egestas eros dolor non lacus. Morbi id orci sapien.

                    Mauris quis congue eros. Donec a nibh feugiat, elementum nisi in, bibendum velit. Morbi non est at urna convallis interdum ac ac mi. 
                    Donec pretium nulla sit amet dapibus dapibus. Mauris interdum sed mauris eu congue. Nunc id adipiscing elit. 
                    Aenean risus mi, tempus vel lectus sed, egestas pulvinar mi. Vestibulum dolor erat, tempor at erat sit amet, 
                    consectetur scelerisque felis.

                    Aenean sit amet congue velit. Sed tincidunt facilisis fringilla. Ut feugiat dolor sed risus vehicula facilisis. 
                    Integer dolor ligula, porttitor a mi eu, hendrerit fermentum tortor. Sed et dui arcu. Donec dui sem, tincidunt quis lorem fringilla, 
                    rutrum hendrerit arcu. Suspendisse quis arcu tincidunt, tincidunt risus condimentum, sodales massa. 
                    Maecenas aliquet elit in tortor placerat, nec sagittis augue condimentum. Integer laoreet vitae erat semper pharetra. 
                    Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Donec egestas nisi nec mi facilisis, 
                    eget ultricies est posuere. Integer tempor bibendum pellentesque.

                    Nulla pretium sollicitudin mi id rhoncus. Aliquam eget congue nunc. Maecenas tincidunt nulla quis metus pellentesque pulvinar. 
                    Maecenas tincidunt sapien ac odio aliquam, id malesuada sem condimentum. Nam neque eros, aliquet non sem ut, ornare rutrum libero. 
                    Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Donec et leo metus. Fusce elit nunc, elementum vitae egestas sit amet, 
                    consectetur nec ipsum.

                    Aenean nisl libero, rutrum eget lacinia vel, faucibus ultrices turpis. Nullam nunc metus, auctor sed mi in, convallis euismod mi.
                    Nulla pulvinar scelerisque mauris vel varius. Nunc eu condimentum odio, eget placerat sem. Integer suscipit,
                    sapien vitae laoreet convallis, velit nibh pellentesque felis, quis tristique nulla orci eu felis. 
                    Duis eu turpis rutrum, malesuada augue vitae, posuere nisi. Etiam vitae dolor eget dui eleifend fermentum. Mauris convallis, 
                    risus vitae congue ultricies, nibh velit vehicula arcu, at tempor risus metus vitae diam. Donec pretium euismod mi id porta. 
                    Integer dictum diam at erat feugiat, eu fringilla mi molestie. Phasellus interdum ultricies aliquet. Donec a elementum risus. 
                    Phasellus non fringilla tellus, eu convallis augue. Aliquam enim lectus, vulputate ut sem et, fringilla commodo erat. 
                    Aliquam urna magna, auctor scelerisque nisi a, egestas tempor nulla.

                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec ac felis sed eros bibendum tincidunt.
                    In vel lectus sit amet velit ullamcorper sollicitudin eu lacinia nisi.
                    Ut sagittis massa non ultricies hendrerit. Fusce non mauris augue. Phasellus imperdiet nisi quis ante commodo dignissim.
                    Aenean vel bibendum ipsum. Proin lobortis lobortis felis nec aliquet. Nunc vestibulum quis enim eu venenatis.
                    Vivamus consectetur justo nec quam euismod, ac pellentesque justo varius. Morbi vel dolor at nisi dictum convallis nec eu ligula. 
                    Duis consequat purus ut neque bibendum convallis. Aliquam tempor justo diam, sed dapibus diam laoreet aliquam. 
                    Curabitur feugiat neque quis nunc tincidunt porttitor. Integer in nulla metus. Proin pulvinar, massa quis bibendum ullamcorper, 
                    arcu arcu convallis mi, ut egestas eros dolor non lacus. Morbi id orci sapien.
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>


    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    !function ($) {

  $(function(){

    var $window = $(window)
    var $body   = $(document.body)

    var navHeight = $('.navbar').outerHeight(true) + 10

    $body.scrollspy({
      target: '.bs-sidebar',
      offset: navHeight
    })

    $window.on('load', function () {
      $body.scrollspy('refresh')
    })

    $('.bs-docs-container [href=#]').click(function (e) {
      e.preventDefault()
    })

    // back to top
    setTimeout(function () {
      var $sideBar = $('.bs-sidebar')

      $sideBar.affix({
        offset: {
          top: function () {
            var offsetTop      = $sideBar.offset().top
            var sideBarMargin  = parseInt($sideBar.children(0).css('margin-top'), 10)
            var navOuterHeight = $('.bs-docs-nav').height()

            return (this.top = offsetTop - navOuterHeight - sideBarMargin)
          }
        , bottom: function () {
            return (this.bottom = $('.bs-footer').outerHeight(true))
          }
        }
      })
    }, 100)

    setTimeout(function () {
      $('.bs-top').affix()
    }, 100)

    // tooltip demo
    $('.tooltip-demo').tooltip({
      selector: "[data-toggle=tooltip]",
      container: "body"
    })

    $('.tooltip-test').tooltip()
    $('.popover-test').popover()

    $('.bs-docs-navbar').tooltip({
      selector: "a[data-toggle=tooltip]",
      container: ".bs-docs-navbar .nav"
    })
})

}(window.jQuery)
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Here's a JSFiddle of your code: http://jsfiddle.net/jdwire/eytMx/embedded/result/

Comment: I think the issue can be reproduced at http://fiddle.jshell.net/jdwire/eytMx/show/light/.

Comment: thanks for the effort @Joshua i think there is some weird flickering between affix-bottom and affix on that fiddle which i dont get from the original code http://www51.zippyshare.com/v/5526428/file.html - perhaps something to do with the fiddle sandbox?

Comment: I did notice some flickering but couldn't tell if that was part of the issue you're having. See my answer for a fiddle that seems to work right and doesn't flicker.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I messed with the JavaScript for a while and here's what I came up with:

```
! function ($) {
    $(function () {
        var $window = $(window)
        var $body = $(document.body)
        var $sideBar = $('.bs-sidebar')
        var navHeight = $('.navbar').outerHeight(true) + 10

        $body.scrollspy({
            target: '.bs-sidebar',
            offset: navHeight
        })

        $('.bs-docs-container [href=#]').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault()
        })

        $window.on('resize', function () {
            $body.scrollspy('refresh')
            // We were resized. Check the position of the nav box
            $sideBar.affix('checkPosition')
        })

        $window.on('load', function () {
            $body.scrollspy('refresh')
            $('.bs-top').affix();
            $sideBar.affix({
                offset: {
                    top: function () {
                        var offsetTop = $sideBar.offset().top
                        var sideBarMargin = parseInt($sideBar.children(0).css('margin-top'), 10)
                        var navOuterHeight = $('.bs-docs-nav').height()

                        // We can cache the height of the header (hence the this.top=)
                        // This function will never be called again.
                        return (this.top = offsetTop - navOuterHeight - sideBarMargin);
                    },
                    bottom: function () {
                        // We can't cache the height of the footer, since it could change
                        // when the window is resized. This function will be called every
                        // time the window is scrolled or resized
                        return $('.bs-footer').outerHeight(true)
                    }
                }
            })
            setTimeout(function () {
                // Check the position of the nav box ASAP
                $sideBar.affix('checkPosition')
            }, 10);
            setTimeout(function () {
                // Check it again after a while (required for IE)
                $sideBar.affix('checkPosition')
            }, 100);
        });

        // tooltip demo
        $('.tooltip-demo').tooltip({
            selector: "[data-toggle=tooltip]",
            container: "body"
        })

        $('.tooltip-test').tooltip()
        $('.popover-test').popover()

        $('.bs-docs-navbar').tooltip({
            selector: "a[data-toggle=tooltip]",
            container: ".bs-docs-navbar .nav"
        })
    })
}(window.jQuery)
```

I think this behaves like what you want.

The key was getting all of the recalculations to happen at the right time. Nothing seemed to be checking the position of the nav box when the page was reloaded. The height of the footer also needed to be recalculated every time because the footer changes height when the page is resized.

I also had to play with the timing of things. Notice that there are two setTimeouts with different delays but the same code. This is to attempt to get the position check done soon but also wait long enough for IE.

See the comments in the code for more details.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jdwire/2XXRF/25/

Full Screen Result: http://fiddle.jshell.net/jdwire/2XXRF/25/show/light/

Comment: Good found. Yes, the height of the footer will vary with the screen size. Beside that this question will be very similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18799688/bootstrap-affix-navbar-for-single-page-with-scrollspy-and-page-anchors/18834770

Comment: @Joshua, thanks, for me the fiddle is running the sidebar off the top and bottom on scroll. I agree that the element top is not being recalculated when page resizes and hence the divs containing the content change themselves. This results in many of the issues. I cant see affix.js recalculating at any point thouhg http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/assets/js/bootstrap-affix.js

Comment: @g18c What browser are you using? It's not running off the top and bottom for me.

Comment: @g18c I couldn't reproduce the issue in Chrome, but found and fixed some issues in IE9. Can you check out http://fiddle.jshell.net/jdwire/2XXRF/20/show/light/ and see if it works right for you?

Comment: @g18c And here's one that works even better in IE: [Preview](http://fiddle.jshell.net/jdwire/2XXRF/21/show/light/) and [Code](http://jsfiddle.net/jdwire/2XXRF/21/). The previous one didn't update the position of the nav box on refresh.

Comment: @JoshuaDwire that last link seems to be 100% fixes all of the issues i saw in Chrome and IE... thank you! Will let you know on further testing but so far under normal use works great. Would it be possible to edit your answer with the changes made, and why, this would help me learn and be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @g18c Just updated the answer. I don't remember everything that I changed, but I've added more explanation to my answer and comments in code and fiddle.

Comment: The fiddle no longer works because of the Bootstrap version

Answer (score 5):

You are using javascript from Twitter's Docs. The first comments of these scripts are:

> // NOTICE!! DO NOT USE ANY OF THIS JAVASCRIPT // IT'S ALL JUST JUNK
>   FOR OUR DOCS! // ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

These script handle problem / fixes for this pages only. Try to fix your problems with the original Bootstrap plugins or extend them for you specific situation.

Also read this questions which handle similar problems:

- [Bootstrap affix navbar for single page with scrollspy and page anchors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18799688/bootstrap-affix-navbar-for-single-page-with-scrollspy-and-page-anchors/18834770)
- [Bootstrap 3 - Scrollspy with sidebar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18914080/bootstrap-3-scrollspy-with-sidebar/18926686)
- [Bootstrap 3RC1 + Side Panel + Affix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18114351/bootstrap-3rc1-side-panel-affix/18966454)

Comment: I think that notice is probably just to let developers know that those files aren't part of the Bootstrap core. Their JavaScript does provide real examples of how to use Bootstrap. It can serve as a basis for development, but it will need to be changed to suit the situation.

Comment: You are right maybe. Bootstrap Docs work well so it could be useful to see how they did it. But unless you will build exactly the same starting at the core files seems easier in most cases i think.

Answer (score 5):

I think you could simplify this a lot by using and understanding the relevant portions of the CSS and JavaScript from the docs.

The most complex part is the #sidebar CSS. Using `.affix` will remove the sidebar from the typical flow of the page, so you need to set a specific width for the `#sidebar`. The CSS handles the 3 cases for the sidebar position (affix, affix-top and affix-bottom). 2 different media queries are used so that the sidebar affix is only applied on larger screens >992px, and slightly wider on >1200px..

**CSS**

```
.affix-top,.affix{
    position: static;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 992px) {

  #sidebar .nav > .active > ul {
    display: block;
  }
  #sidebar.affix-top {
    position: static;
    margin-top:30px;
    width:228px;
  }

  #sidebar.affix,
  #sidebar.affix-bottom {
    width: 228px;
  }
  #sidebar.affix {
    position: fixed;
    top: 220px;
  }
  #sidebar.affix-bottom {
    position: absolute;
  }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
  #sidebar.affix-bottom,
  #sidebar.affix {
    width: 235px;
  }
}
```

The other important part is the javascript that calculates the height of the header **(`#masthead`)** *above the sidebar*, and **`footer`** *below the sidebar*. These heights are used to determine where `affix` will become sticky at the top, and return to absolute position at the bottom when the footer is visible in the viewport.

**JavaScript**

```
$('#sidebar').affix({
      offset: {
        top: function () {
          var navOuterHeight = $('#masthead').height();
          return this.top = navOuterHeight;
        },
        bottom: function () {
          return (this.bottom = $('footer').outerHeight(true))
        }
      }
});
```

Here is a working example / template: **http://bootply.com/84981**